# Enable Wi-Fi tethering via Bluetooth?

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, bluetooth-tethering

Bluetooth uses low power, and hence I keep it enabled indefinitely for whenever I want to tether with my laptop.

Wi-Fi is much faster and thus I prefer it over Bluetooth, but I can't keep the access point enabled indefinitely as it drains my battery too quickly.

Is there some way for me to enable & disable the Wi-Fi access point via its permanent Bluetooth connection to my laptop so that I can get faster tethering without having to keep the Wi-Fi access point enabled (and without having to touch my phone to enable/disable it)?

Comment: I don't know about any way doing that via Bluetooth. But would an alternative using NFC be acceptable, too? You didn't name your device, so I cannot tell if it supports NFC. Another option I could name would be "location aware", i.e. enabling WiFi whenever you're in a certain location, and disabling it when you leave it. Or similarly acting whenever another Bluetooth device is in reach (or gets out of reach).

Comment: @Izzy: I see. Nope NFC isn't an option -- my laptop doesn't have NFC! But if I could make the Wi-Fi turn on whenever another Bluetooth device is in or out of reach that could be very useful too! How would I do that?

Comment: We cannot help you with your Laptop here, this site is about Android. See my answer for the Android part below, hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing actions whenever a certain Blutooth device is in reach *and paired* (and reverting them when it gets out of reach) can be done e.g. with [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) (see the [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) for details on the app):

- **Condition:** *BT Connected* (parameter: name or address of the device)
- **Task:** *WiFi* (parameter: *On*)
- **Exit-Task:** (optional; *Tasker* should revert automatically to the previous state when the condition is no longer met) *WiFi* (parameter: *Off*)

This would similarly work with NFC when using the NFC plugin. More features are also offered by other plugins. Also see my [Collection of Tasker Ressources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) for tutorials and available plugins.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. All I need to do now is just double-click my Bluetooth device and the Wi-Fi access point automatically appears! (The correct task for this seems to be "Wi-Fi Tether", not "Wi-Fi".)

Comment: Ah – *facepalm* sure, that's where the laptop comes in. Sorry for the lapsus. You're correct, in this case it's not "WiFi" but "WiFi Tether" :) But you've got the idea, so it wasn't that bad ;) Guess you'll find a lot of other interesting things you can do with *Tasker* – enjoy!